# Is apache2 reload for .conf changes only or is it allowable to be used when application code changes?

Tags: python, http, apache2, webserver, wsgi

When the code for my python WSGI applicaiton changes should I use apache2's reload or graceful restart feature?

Currently we use reload, but have noticed that sometimes the application does not load properly and errors pertaining to missing modules are logged to the error files even though the modules have existed for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should probably use graceful.  But if your application is not exiting correctly you may have to force it with just restart.

For wsgi, you should try running in daemon mode.  When it is running in daemon mode, you can restart your service just by touching the wsgi file and updating its timestamp.  This will reload all the code without restarting apache.

Here is more info: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

This is for django, but may be useful for your project: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

Answer (score 0):

The 'reload' and 'graceful' would have the same effect as far as reloading your web application. If you are seeing issues with imports like you describe, it is likely to be an issue in your application code with you having import order dependencies or import cycles. One sees this a lot with people using Django. Suggest you actually post an example of the error you are getting.